# Just what is "host" command querying?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

Trying to debug a slow connection problem and this occurs:

```
root@agile:/var/atlassian/application-data/jira# host mysql-server
mysql-server.novalocal has address 10.10.0.5
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

So the nameserver correctly results the hostname but then fails on something. Any ideas what?

Comment: We tracked it down - it was doing an IPV6 AAAA record lookup which was being incorrectly forwarded across our network and on to Google's nameservers who were of course not responding as the domain is not public.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you do `host -v mysql-server` you will see what `host` is querying. Likely it is performing multiple queries (it did on my box, first it queried for A record, then for AAAA record and finally for MX record) and due to some DNS / name resolution configuration issue one of the queries fails.

You might actually try the three different queries individually by issuing the following commands to see which of them times out:

```
host -t A mysql-server
host -t AAAA mysql-server
host -t MX mysql-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have mysql-server.novalocal in your /etc/hosts?

You can try `"host -a mysql-server"` and it should tell you where it got the answer from.

It will try to query the DNS which is currently used by your system.

Have a look at /etc/resolv.conf to get more info!

Edit: `"host -v mysql-server"` might work too.

Comment: Using `-a` alters the way `host` is making the query, so the result might not be the same.

Comment: In which way does it alter the query?

Comment: As the man page says, it makes host to query for record type "any" as opposed to the default of querying for A, AAAA and MX in succession, i.e. it is equivalent of `-t ANY -v`